# Render a template with 60fps

Tags: rendering, frame-rate

I have a small problem with blender render, I have a template and I want to make it smooth so I set frame rate at 60 but it become so fast, how to fix it ??

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is increase the number of frames that your animation takes. Go to the dope sheet and select "action editor" now select all of your keyframes with A and press S and then press 2. This would slow down your animation by half.

Edit: I will add images to show you

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can see, now the animation takes up double the amount of frames. Meaning it will take twice s long to complete, meaning it will be half as fast.

Comment: I opend dope sheet and select all keyframes but press s and 2. but nothing happend ?? how to do it exactly ??

Comment: @Ahmed Check out my edited answer. Let me know if that helps